# next js className haven't been set

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I've just started playing with next js. so I want to use css as module and setup classname for nav, but in rendered DOM this classname doesn't exist. I can see generated styles by webpack in "head" tag, but I dont see classname on my nav tag.

```
import React from "react";
import styles from './NavigationContainer.module.scss';

type Props = {};

const NavigationContainer: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
    return <nav className={styles.mainNavigationContainer}>{children}</nav>
};

export default NavigationContainer;
```

[image: styles]
[image: nav]

Comment: It should be `styles.main-navigator-container` right? The CSS selector & styles.[name] should be the same can you please try this?

Comment: looks like a kebab-case to camelCase problem, see this issue: [CSS modules - converting class names to camelCase automatically](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11267)

Comment: @RajendranNadar it works. but I'm just wondering, what the purpose of this property in camelcase. Auto complete shows me that this prop exists

Comment: Actually, in JS, we cannot use `-` as a variable name it is considered as a minus to do the math. Not sure why autocomplete is showing it maybe it converted from kebab case to camelcase and matched the value?

Comment: @RajendranNadar with the correct loader config css names using kebab-case should be automatically converted to camelCase, this is so that one can adhere to naming conventions in both CSS and JS. See the issue linked in my prior comment.

Comment: ok I was searching for that on the docs, it should be documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, we cannot use `-` as a variable name it is considered as a minus to do the math.

It is a good idea to rename the CSS selector to `.mainNavigationContainer` so that the Next Js can get the correct CSS styles.

The JS part will remain the same.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css